# is there a way i can autofill a form in django forms

Tags: python, django

i am trying to get data to be autofilled that i am getting from a code generator . so without needing a user to fill it in i want it to be already filled

```
from django.utils.crypto import get_random_string
unique_id = get_random_string(length=32)


class UserRegisterForm(UserCreationForm):
    
    email = forms.EmailField()

    

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username','email','password1','password2']



class Bybitapidata(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Bybitapidatas
        fields = ('apikey','apisecret','sectoken')
        widgets = {
        'apikey': TextInput(attrs={
            'class': "form-control",
            'style': 'max-width: 300px;',
            'placeholder': 'Bybit Api Key'
            }),
        'apisecret': TextInput(attrs={
            'class': "form-control", 
            'style': 'max-width: 300px;',
            'placeholder': 'Bybit Api Secret'
            }),
        'sectoken': TextInput(attrs={
            'class': "form-control", 
            'style': 'max-width: 300px;',
            'placeholder': 'Please enter a  12 Digit token'#here i want to automatically give 12 digits that is being generated
            })
    }
```

Comment: You can use initial data in the form fields for this. Can you post your view code as well? Also, which form needs to be pre-filled?

Comment: thanks i have tried it but i use request.POST , initial = initial_data) then it ignores the initial data part

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to generate a random token with one of this options that i give to you, I hope you like it! :)

```
import secrets
token_generator = token_urlsafe(16)  
        'sectoken': TextInput(attrs={
            'class': "form-control", 
            'style': 'max-width: 300px;',
            'placeholder': token_generator
            })
    }
```

Another example:

```
import string
import random

length= 16
token_generator =''.join(random.choices(string.ascii_letters+string.digits,k=length))
```

Comment: 'sectoken': TextInput(attrs={
            'class': "form-control", 
            'style': 'max-width: 300px;',
            'placeholder': unique_id
            })

    }
this worked perfectly but it is now as a place holder which is good but is there a way to use it as initial data

Comment: ```        initial_data={
            'sectoken': unique_id
        }
        form = Bybitapidata(request.POST , initial = initial_data)
```i have this in views
request.POST , initial = initial_data) but since i have request.post it ignores the initial